# SFML RenderWindow Unhandled Exception

Tags: c++, sfml

So I've been following an SFML tutorial but unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be working.  The tutorial shows a RenderWindow as a global variable and then accesses it like this:

```
LevelState.h:

struct LevelStateAssets
{
sf::Texture img_background;
sf::Texture img_player;
sf::Texture img_enemy;
};

extern LevelStateAssets ls_Assets;

class LevelState : public StateBase
{
public:
    LevelState();
    void Input(sf::Event event);
    void Update(void);
    void Render(void);

private:
    sf::Sprite spr_background;
};

LevelState.cpp:

LevelStateAssets ls_Assets;

LevelState::LevelState()
{
ls_Assets.img_background.loadFromFile("res/images/background.png");
ls_Assets.img_player.loadFromFile("res/images/player.png");
ls_Assets.img_enemy.loadFromFile("res/images/enemy.png");

spr_background.setTexture(ls_Assets.img_background);
spr_background.setPosition(0, 0);
}
/* More unnecessary code in the middle */

void LevelState::Render(void)
{
window.draw(spr_background);
}
```

But when I do this, I get an error that says: "Unhandled exception at 0x774F3632 (ntdll.dll) in SFMLTutorial.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000004"

If you could help me that would be great!
Thanks for your time! :)

Comment: From just quickly looking over this I wonder where you defined ls_Assets? You declared it in the header but apparently did not define it in the cpp file.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add that, I did define it (The main post is updated with it now).

Comment: Is this from a bad youtube tutorial?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never make your sf::RenderWindow global.

The [SFML developer stated that global RenderWindow can cause issues](http://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=9636.msg65799#msg65799):

> Don't declare your RenderWindow in global scope, something happens in its constructor and some internal objects of SFML might not be initialized at this point.

Comment: You should elaborate.

Comment: Hope it's better.

Comment: Indeed, perfect.  A non-expert like me has no way to know that your answer is exactly right without a reference.

Comment: Ok, thanks!  I guess I won't be using that tutorial...